# How to know a user switch the their account to use as page account?

Tags: php, facebook

From FB PHP SKD

How to know a user switch the their account to use as page account when the user switched "Use Facebook as PAGE_NAME"?

Many thanks for any your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User cannot interact with your application canvas and application tab canvas while working in a "Use as Page" mode. He will be prompted to switch back to be a regular user before visiting canvas.

**Update:**

Just checked and is the same for Sites using Facebook JS-SDK. While old cookie set by JS-SDK is preserved and not removed and no auth related events is fired using `FB.login` prompts user to switch to his normal account.

Comment: +1: and at server side (PHP) how can I detect a user who have switched?

Comment: As sad as it may be at server side you'll never know it.
Nothing will be passed to you in that case (PHP-SDK will still be using existing cookie for user itself), and facebook wouldn't let him to authorize as page with application.